# Take an action when user switches tabs on an NSTabView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstabview

I have an application that contains an `NSTabView`. Whenever the user changes tabs, I need to run an operation. How can I do that?

Comment: provide Code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure from your question, but I think you're looking for the one of the `NSTabViewDelegate` methods `tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:` or `tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:`. These methods will be called on the tab view's delegate when it changes tab view items.

Comment: How can I implement this method? And in what part of the code?

Comment: You need to create a class (or modify an existing class you already have) to conforms to the `NSTabViewDelegate` protocol:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

The protocol has no required methods, so you can just implement whichever method you need. Then set an instance of that class as the delegate of your `NSTabView`, either through interface builder or through code.